# Point clustering based on a certain value

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, polygon, clustering, geometry-conversion

I'm trying to cluster points based on the sum of a attributes of its nearest neighbors.
So here are the points in the data set as they are:[image: base point lists]

The objective is that each point has an "evalfield" attribute associated with it. I want to be able to cluster them such that the sum of the clustered points ad up to a predetermined value that I decide.(last column).

[image: The attribute table]

To illustrate with an example:
Here are a collection of points , with their attribute on the basis for which clustering is too occur written above them.
(0.5,0.6 etc.)

I want to be able to cluster them such that the sum of this value in a cluster adds up to a predetermined value (1.1 in this case)
[image: End objective]

**EDIT**

So I followed the steps and pretty much copied out the code as is to run it in qgis.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import geometry as geom


gdf = gpd.read_file('filteredptlst.shp')
exploded_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
exploded_gdf.crs = gdf.crs


print('starting ...')


for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
    if float(row['evalfield']) == 0.01:
        exploded_gdf = exploded_gdf.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        for i in range(0, int(row['evalfield']*100)):
            entry = row.copy()
            entry['evalfield'] = 0.01
            exploded_gdf = exploded_gdf.append(entry, ignore_index=True)


print('processing done ... saving')

gdf.to_file(driver='ESRI Shapefile', filename="result.shp")

print('saved')
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Python Console 
Use iface to access QGIS API interface or Type help(iface) for more info
execfile(u'C:/Users/USER/OneDrive/Documents/Studies etc/adrchitectural design/thesis/Thesisgisdata/Siteselectionalgs/alg1_point_filtering_explosion.py'.encode('mbcs'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/Users/USER/OneDrive/Documents/Studies etc/adrchitectural design/thesis/Thesisgisdata/Siteselectionalgs/alg1_point_filtering_explosion.py", line 24, in <module>
    gdf = gpd.read_file('filteredptlst.shp')
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 19, in read_file
    with fiona.open(filename, **kwargs) as f:
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py", line 170, in open
    raise IOError("no such file or directory: %r" % path)
IOError: no such file or directory: 'filteredptlst.shp'
```

Ive already tried changing the project environment and putting in a complete file path to the location of the file.

I couldn't se anything wrong with the code so I ran it separately in Visual Studio ,  but that doesn't seem to work either , there are no trackback errors but none of the print messages which I put I ( to check) arent't displayed either.

P.S. I'm really new to both GIS and Python and there must be something really obvious I'm overlooking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE : I'm using here some packages that you didn't mention in your tags

My suggestion would be to first explode your points data to the unit (like 0.1), this means a point that have a value of 0.5 will generate five points each have a value of 0.1

**EDIT :** to explode your points you can loop through your dataset and create new points when your value isn't equal to 0.1

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import geometry as geom

gdf = gpd.read_file('your_points.shp')
exploded_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame()
exploded_gdf.crs = gdf.crs 
for index, row in gdf.iterrows():
    if row['your_value'] == 0.1:
        exploded_gdf = exploded_gdf.append(row, ignore_index = True)
    else:
        for i in range(0, row['your_value']*10):
             entry = row.copy()
             entry['your_value'] = 0.1
             exploded_gdf = exploded_gdf.append(entry, ignore_index = True)
```

here take a look at this you'll like it [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/)

then run [K-means](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.vq.kmeans2.html) clustering algorithm from scipy package to cluster your points:

```
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2, whiten
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

gdf = gpd.read_file('your_exploded_points.shp')
coordinates = np.array(list(gdf['geometry'].apply(lambda x: list(x.coords[0]))))
x, y = kmeans2(whiten(coordinates), int(math.ceil(len(coordinates)/your_value_of_cluster*10)) , iter = 10, minit = 'points')
# you can tune the parameter iter to get the best results
```

Comment: I'm open to solving this in some other way.

Kinda a newbie here , how do I go about exploding the point data like you said?

Comment: @rangeet I've edited my answer to explode your points

Comment: So I think I need a little help with the python console, I realize that I'm straying from the original question but I might as well finish up on all my problems here

Comment: @rangeet the error you are getting is because of a wrong path of the shapefile provided, you'll have to specify the correct path of the shapefile instead of just the name in `gpd.read_file(...)`